# Data structure that supports random access by index and key, insertion, deletion in logaritmic time with order maintained

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, random-access

I'm looking for the data structure that stores an ordered list of E = (K, V) elements and supports the following operations in at most O(log(N)) time where N is the number of elements. Memory usage is not a problem.

- E get(index) // get element by index
- int find(K) // find the index of the element whose K matches
- delete(index) // delete element at index, the following elements have their indexes decreased by 1
- insert(index, E) // insert element at index, the following elements have their indexes increased by 1

I have considered the following incorrect solutions:

- Use array: `find`, `delete`, and `insert` will still  O(N)
- Use array + map of K to index: `delete` and `insert` will still cost O(N) for shifting elements and updating map
- Use linked list + map of K to element address: `get` and `find` will still cost O(N)

In my imagination, the last solution is the closest, but instead of linked list, a self-balancing tree where each node stores the number of elements on the left of it will make it possible for us to do `get` in O(log(N)).

However I'm not sure if I'm correct, so I want to ask whether my imagination is correct and whether there is a name for this kind of data structure so I can look for off-the-shelf solution.

Comment: +1 for waiting an answer. I doubt is it possible, as you have to support find() in O(lg N) using either key or index, but the structure (that I know) can only be sorted by either key or index or value...

Comment: @shole Agree , I too think you can pick 3 operations out of asked 4 operations and support O(logn) not all 4. It might be better if the question is tagged in cs.stackexchange.com as well

Comment: A standard balanced binary search tree where each node stores the count of its children should be enough to support all of your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The closest data structure i could think of is [treaps](https://e-maxx-eng.appspot.com/data_structures/treap.html).

> Implicit treap is a simple modification of the regular treap which is a very powerful data structure. In fact, implicit treap can be considered as an array with the following procedures implemented (all in O(logN)O(log⁡N) in the online mode):
>
> 1. Inserting an element in the array in any location
> 2. Removal of an arbitrary element
> 3. Finding sum, minimum / maximum element etc. on an arbitrary interval
> 4. Addition, painting on an arbitrary interval
> 5. Reversing elements on an arbitrary interval

Using modification with implicit keys allows you to do all operation except the second one (find the index of the element whose K matches). I'll edit this answer if i come up with a better idea :)

Comment: A treap is asymptotically no better than a general balanced binary search tree.

Comment: @devouredelysium you are right, it's no better comparing get or delete operations, but it can't delete and insert elements at index, increasing or decreasing indexes of other elements. As treap supports addition on interval, it's possible. Actually, [segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) should do as well